# bad URI(is not URI?) when using click_link

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, capybara

I have a code line that looks like this:

```
click_link "link page with spaces"
```

The link looks like this in the HTML:

```
<a href="page with spaces">link page with spaces</a>
```

When this line runs I get:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): page with spaces
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
```

I understand that the problem is because the link contains spaces which are not converted to `%20` but I'm not sure on how to solve it.

Comment: Give the actual html,so that we can see it..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I gave the href. What else is missing?

Comment: @ the url link I am talking about.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit Ohh, I can't it's in inner network. I know the problem is the spaces. I also saw some other posts with this problem but all of them didn't use `click_link`

Comment: @ArupRakshit - the solution was always to run `URI.parse` on the link before using it. But I can't do it in this case because `click_link` calls the link

Answer (score 0):

Could you just escape the uri wherever it's being generated?

```
require 'uri'
URI.escape("page with spaces") # => "page%20with%20spaces"
```

Comment: Sadly no. The page that generates the URI is not under my control.